# Map dynamic variable in php

Tags: php, rest

How can I assign value to an element from a REST api call?

Say given I have a result of `4` in an api call `echo $resultArray[0]['number'][0]['value'];`. Then I want to assign corresponding value to that result, so whenever I issue the next call, I should get `House` as the result.

```
Assigning string values:
    4 = House
    5 = Bedroom
```

UPDATE:

```
[{"number":[{"value":4}],"uuid":[{"value":"123-123-123-123-123"}],"vid":[{"value":123}],"langcode":[{"value":"en"}],"type":[{"target_id":"test","target_type":"test_type","target_uuid":"456-456-456-456-456"}],"revision_timestamp":[{"value":123345678}],"revision_uid":[{"target_id":1,"target_type":"user","target_uuid":"321-321-321-321-321","url":"\/user\/1\/stream"}],"revision_log":[],"status":[{"value":false}],"title":[{"value":"John Test Patch"}]}]
```

Comment: can you please explain more

Comment: do you try this :
$resultArray[0]['number'][0]['value'] = 4 ; 
are you looking for that ?

Comment: or make a test like : 
if($resultArray[0]['number'][0]['value'] == "house"){
$resultArray[0]['number'][0]['value'] = 4 ;
}

Comment: may be i understand what you are looking for , so let's suppose that you have a list of object returned from you api and you want to assign some value if some condition are true... if i'm right , can you show me the  $resultArray result . and then i can hold this treatment

Comment: print your $resultArray in the discription and then i give you the solution .

Comment: Its updated now.

Comment: what if you try to print it with a lot of object . that will be more clair . please

Comment: please check again...

Comment: you are updating an invalid json . can you check it please

Comment: okay. It should be in right format now.

Comment: it's ok . check me answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168845/discussion-between-mohammed-yassine-chabli-and-john-rey-tanquinco).

Answer (score 0):

maintain an associative array for storing sting and value.
match the result in the associative array to display the desired value.

```
    $mapArray = array('4'=>'home','5'=>'office');
    $response_decoded=json_decode($response,true); //$response is json from api call.
    if(isset($mapArray[$response_decoded['number']['0']['value']])
    {
        $response_decoded['number']['0']['value']=$mapArray[$response_decoded['number']['0']['value']];
}
    else
    {
        echo "value not present in array";
    }
```

Comment: can you please be more specific by adding sample code to what you are referring to?

Answer (score 0):

let's suppose you have this $resultArray already decoded  as reponse from you api  , to hold that with php  , try this :

```
if(!empty($resultArray)){
foreach($resultArray as $key => $object){
    if($object->number[0]->value ==4){
        $object->number[0]->value= "house";
    }
    else if($object->number[0]->value ==5){
      $object->number[0]->value= "Bedroom";
    }
     // if you have another use case  add them after here 
    /* else if(){
     }
     .
     .
     else(){
     }
     */
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$var = $resultArray[0]['number'][0]['value'];
switch($var){
 case 0:
  $varString = "text"; 
  break;

case 4: 
 $varString = "House";
 break;

case default:
 $varString = "not 0 or 4"; 
 break; 
}
```

That should do the trick for you :)